# Generate Random number between 0 and 10

Tags: c++, math, random

How can i generate Random numbers between 0 and 10? Can I have a sample for this random number generation?

Comment: randomness is tricky to do properly, you should first identify what you need random numbers for. rand may be fine for an rpg dice throw but totally unsuitable for a game involving money, anything involving cryptography or modelling noise is DSP simulations

Comment: Most of the time you will do fine with Mersenne Twister.

Comment: Another question where user692270 accepts @karthik question.

Comment: @SebastianMach The accepted answer was posted 2 minutes after the question was posted. The answer is identified as being by karthik, who asked the question ... was it previously identified as posted by user692270, presumably a sockpuppet?

Comment: @JimBalter: I guess they have been merged. Either that, or a ban. But my bet is on the merger.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
  /* rand example: guess the number */
  #include <stdio.h>
  #include <stdlib.h>
  #include <time.h>

  int main ()
  {
       int iSecret, iGuess;

       /* initialize random seed: */
       srand ( time(NULL) );

       /* generate secret number: */
       iSecret = rand() % 10 + 1;

        do {
          printf ("Guess the number (1 to 10): ");
          scanf ("%d", &iGuess);
          if (iSecret < iGuess) puts ("The secret number is lower");
          else if (iSecret > iGuess) puts ("The secret number is higher");
        } while (iSecret != iGuess);

      puts ("Congratulations!");
      return 0;
    }
```

**iSecret** variable will provide the random numbers between 1 and 10

Comment: @JimBalter: Not really; self-answering is not only acceptable, but indeed encouraged. And, back in 2011, there was no way to post the answer with the question simultaneously.

Comment: Allow me to mention from where this code was taken from (identical, with some small format adjustments which I made for the if/else conditions, which were not considering space characters): https://cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/rand/?kw=rand

Answer (score 16):

1) You shouldn't use `rand()`, it has bad distribution, short period etc...

2) You shouldn't use `%x` when `MaxValue % x != 0` because you mess your uniform distribution (suppose you don't use rand()), e.g. `32767 % 10 = 7` so number 0-7 are more likely to get

Watch this for more info: [Going native 2013 -  Stephan T. Lavavej - rand() Considered Harmful](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/rand-Considered-Harmful)

You should use something like:

```
#include <random>

std::random_device rdev;
std::mt19937 rgen(rdev());
std::uniform_int_distribution<int> idist(0,10); //(inclusive, inclusive)
```

I in my codes use something like this:

```
template <typename T>
T Math::randomFrom(const T min, const T max)
{
    static std::random_device rdev;
    static std::default_random_engine re(rdev());
    typedef typename std::conditional<
        std::is_floating_point<T>::value,
        std::uniform_real_distribution<T>,
        std::uniform_int_distribution<T>>::type dist_type;
    dist_type uni(min, max);
    return static_cast<T>(uni(re));
}
```

NOTE: the implementation is not thread safe and constructs a distribution for every call. That's inefficient. But you can modify it for your needs.

Answer (score 3):

See this example of a uniform integer distribution in `boost::random`:

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/doc/html/boost_random/tutorial.html#boost_random.tutorial.generating_integers_in_a_range

Answer (score 2):

`random_integer = rand()%10;` should do the trick I guess.

`random_integer = rand()%11;` for all numbers between 0 and 10, 10 included...

Comment: yup... Bit I think he/she gets the picture :)

Comment: (Not like it practically matters in this case, but note that this will give a slightly biased distribution by design. Modulo is a "wrap around" operation, so for any range of numbers that is not a multiple of the modulus, the output will be biased. Luckily, here the bias is not great because rand() commonly outputs a 32 bit number, and 10 is a comparatively small modulus - the numbers 0 to 5 are only 1.000000023 times more likely than the other ones. That's well within "random noise" and can probably be ignored. Though such a thing may matter if the modulus is much greater.)

Comment: on windows RAND_MAX is only 32767 (15 bits) so there will be about 1/3000 bias against getting a 9 or 10